# Follow twitter users with spring-social and grails

Tags: spring, grails, twitter, spring-social, twitter-follow

I've installed spring social twitter plugin within my grails app but a lot of methods seems to be missings espacially those relatives to friends feeds while the other one are ok

```
TwitterProfile profile = twitter.userOperations().getPublicTimeline(); 
List<Tweet> tweets = twitter.timelineOperations().getFriendsTimeline();
```

and FriendOperations interface does not provide any methods to fllow friends tweets. 
All the other one relative to home account or retweet does work.

Answer (score 0):

```
twitter.friendOperations().follow("username");
```

Comment: Well I don't need to follow new users. Just need to read my followed feeds, which I can't do u know any method ?

Comment: You mea thr timeline you see when you login to twitter?